# Defining absolute value in scrbook

Tags: math-mode

Why does this not work in `scrbook`:

```
\[
\left | x \right |=\left\{\begin{matrix} x, if x\geq 0
\\ -x, if x<0 \end{matrix}\right.
\]
```

(I wrote it in writeLaTeX.)

**if I use the amsmath then bring up a message:**

> "(no line number in this file):
>
> LaTeX Error: Command \ iiint already defined.
>
> Or name \ end ... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.  Type H for immediate help. ...
>
> l.507 ... {\ iiint} {\ DOTSI \ protect \ MultiIntegral {3}}
>
> Your command was ignored. Type I   to replace it with another command, or  to continue without it."

**The codes I've used:**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{helvet} 
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel} 
\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{wasysym} 
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{venndiagram} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{comment} 
\specialcomment{solusi}{\begin{tcolorbox}}{\end{tcolorbox}}
```

Comment: What doesn't work, exactly? You need `\usepackage{amsmath}` by the way.

Comment: plus those entries in the matrix is text, so it is better to write `x & \text{if $x\geq 0$}` and `-x & \text{if $x<0$}` for the second line.

Comment: \documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[bahasa]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{comment}
\specialcomment{solusi}{\begin{tcolorbox}}{\end{tcolorbox}}

Comment: @kalakay Please, add the code to your question rather than in comments.

Comment: Please update your question instead. Comments are not meant for massive amounts of code. Besides that code is not a full minimal example. Please post something can we can copy and compile as is, such that we do not have to add or guess anything.

Comment: Adding your code to the preamble you provided, compiles just fine on my system (TL13)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a backslash character, `\`, between `\left` and `{`.

However, rather than just adding the missing backslash character, you may want to rewrite the entire expression to make use of the `cases` environment to obtain an overall better format.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Original form, with backslash inserted after second \texttt{\textbackslash left}:
\[
\left| x \right|=
\left\{
  \begin{matrix} x, if x\geq 0\\ -x, if x<0 \end{matrix}
\right.
\]

\bigskip
Modified form, using \texttt{cases} environment:
\[
\left | x \right | = 
\begin{cases}
\hfill x & \text{if $x\geq 0$}\\
      -x & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
\] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice trick with the `\hfill`.  I've never thought of that in such a case.  I didn't realize it would work in this context.

Comment: Please note, I wrote it in writeLaTeX, if I use the amsmath then bring up a message:
(no line number in this file): LaTeX Error: C
ommand \ iiint already defined.
Or name \ end ... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
<return> Type H for immediate help.
  ...                                               
l.507 ... {\ iiint} {\ DOTSI \ protect \ MultiIntegral {3}}                                              
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.

Comment: @A.Ellett - Thanks. It works because the left-hand column of a `cases` environment is centered, by default, by placing `\hfil` at either end of the material. The `\hfill` instruction to the left of `x` serves to overpower the implicit `\hfil` that follows the `x`, and the cell ends up being typeset flush-right. :-)

Comment: @kalakay - I'm afraid I'm not familiar with writeLaTeX. Are there maybe other math-related packages you're loading? Have you tried deleting all .aux files and recompiling your document.

Comment: All packages already showed above.

Comment: @kalakay if you are still having problems please edit your _question_ (not comments) to have a _complete_ document (as Mico did in this answer then people have a chance of explaining any error.